# How can I view videos on CNN?

Tags: windows, javascript, browser, flash

I get "The video timed out attempting to play. Please ensure that you do not have any Flash or JavaScript blocking plugins active. " when I try to view CNN news with Firefox on my computer? How to remedy this?

Comment: Do you see the videos with another browsers (ie Internet Explorer, Chrome, etc.....)

Answer (score 0):

Type `about:addons` in your addressbar and disable any plugin that might be blocking flash.
Also recommended : try using another browser to see if its an issue with you firewall blocking any content , in case you are behind a university / company firewall.

Comment: When I input "about:addons" in Firefox browser, I get "The URL is not valid and can not be loaded".

Comment: Firefox version? Get latest.

Comment: yup its time to leave your firefox 3 and embrace firefox 8 :)